# Are three events $A, B$ and $C$ independent, when given following information?

Tags: probability, independence, bayes-theorem

I was under the impression that 3 events are mutually **independent** when A and B, B and C & A and C are all (separately) independent.

Events are independent when:
$P(A \cap B) = P(A) \cdot P(B)$
or equivalently:
$\require{cancel} P(A|B) = P(A)$ (because of Bayes', $P(A|B)=\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} \to P(A|B) = \frac{P(A) \cdot \bcancel{P(B)}}{\bcancel{P(B)}} \to P(A|B) = P(A)$)

So given:
Events A, B and C, s.t. $P(A) = P(B) = 0.4, P(C) = 0.5$ and $P(A \cap B) = 0.16, P(A \cap C) = 0.2, P(B | C) = 0.4$

I calculated:
$P(A \cap B) = 0.16 = 0.4 \cdot 0.4 = P(A) \cdot P(B)$
$P(A \cap C) = 0.2 = 0.4 \cdot 0.5 = P(A) \cdot P(C)$
and
$P(B | C) = 0.4 = 0.4 = P(B)$

I thought this would be more than sufficient to tell that A, B and C are (mutually) independent.
However, I started to doubt when the *solutions* given for this exercise stated that *A, B and C are dependent*.

Please explain why my reasoning is incorrect, or verify that the solutions given were incorrect.

Comment: I don't see any information on $Pr(A\cap B\cap C)$.  Yes, given the current information you can see that $A,B,C$ are pairwise independent however pairwise independence is not by itself enough to imply mutual independence.

Comment: For a trivial example of three pairwise independent events who are not mutually independent, consider the uniform distribution on $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and consider $A=\{1,2\},B=\{1,3\}$ and $C=\{1,4\}$.  In that scenario you have $Pr(A)=Pr(B)=Pr(C)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A\cap C)=Pr(B\cap C) = \frac{1}{4}$ however $Pr(A\cap B\cap C)=\frac{1}{4}\neq \frac{1}{8}$

Comment: So my understanding that if A and B, B and C & A and C are independent, then A, B and C are independent is wrong? What else is a requirement for all 3 to be mutually independent?

Comment: You further require that $Pr(A\cap B\cap C) = Pr(A)\times Pr(B)\times Pr(C)$

Comment: This generalizes to even more events... We say that events $A_1,A_2,A_3,\dots,A_n$ are (*mutually*) independent iff for every subset of the events (*proper or otherwise*) you have the probability of the intersection of the events in the subset is equal to the product of their respective probabilities.